# How to mathematically write: all elements of a set are 0 except one that can be either +1 or -1?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I have a vector $[d] = [d_1, d_2, ..., d_i]$. All elements of $d$ are always $0$ except for one of them which can be either $+1$ or $-1$. How can I write that mathematically?

Comment: $\exists ! d_i (d_i \ne 0)$

Comment: You just did. Why use confusing symbols when you can plainly and quickly say what you want to say in words?

Comment: what you said is absolutely fine actually

Comment: Set $\mathcal S=\{(d_1,...,d_n)\in \mathbb R^n\mid d_i=0\text{ for all $i$ but one which belong to $\{-1,1\}$} \}$. Then take $d\in \mathcal S$...

Comment: If it is known that the $d_i$ are integers, then you can say $|d_1| + \cdots + |d_i| = 1$.

Comment: You say set in the title and vector in the body?  Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You just did. Why use confusing symbols when you can plainly and quickly say what you want to say in words? – Alex Kruckman

Comment is correct.  But if you insist on first order language:

$$\exists k ~.~ (d_k = -1 \lor d_k = 1) \land \forall j ~.~ j \ne k \to d_j = 0$$

Or in less strict language:

$$\begin{array} {l}  \text{for some k} \\ \quad \begin{cases} d_j \in \{-1, 1\} & j = k \\ d_j = 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}  \end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

Commonly, we let $e_1 = [1,0,0,0,\dots,0], e_2 = [0,1,0,0,\dots,0],\dots, e_k = [0,0,\dots,0,\underbrace{1}_{k\text{'th position}},0,\dots,0]$ etc... be the common notation for ["standard basis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20standard%20basis,except%20one%20that%20equals%201.) for $\Bbb R^n$.

Your vector is one of these $\pm e_k$ for some $k$

Answer (score 0):

Define $\mathbb N_i=\{1,2,3,\dots ,i\}$ and say
$$(\forall j\in\Bbb N_i\setminus\{k\}.d_j=0)\land d_k=\pm1$$

However, writing what you wrote (in words) is also absolutely fine I guess.

Comment: That is not how $\forall$ is normally used.

Comment: @MJD can you explain a little more...

Comment: $\forall$ is not simply an abbreviation of the phrase “for each” and it is not normally used as one.  It is a technical part of the syntax of logical expressions, and the syntax does not normally allow $\forall$ in the middle of an expression like that.  A formula with $\forall$ takes the form $⸢\forall x.\Phi(x)⸣$, or $⸢\forall x\in S. \Phi(x)⸣$, where $\Phi$ is some formula in which $x$ is a free variable. Some minor variations are common, but nothing like what you described.  See [this description for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula#Predicate_logic).

Comment: @MJD I'm not much familiar with formal logic, but from what I understood of your comment, do you mean writing "$\forall j\in \mathbb N_i\backslash\{k\}.(d_j=0)\wedge d_k=\pm 1$" would be better? Sorry if this was a stupid question. Thanks for the comments though.

Comment: Yes, that's better, although the parentheses are in the wrong place.  It should be something like $(\forall j\in\Bbb N_i\setminus\{k\}.d_j=0)\land d_k=\pm1$.  It was not a stupid question.

Comment: @MJD thanks. I understand your point now. I'll edit my answer.